# Performing Simultaneous Multiplication in Knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi I'm trying to make a simple calculator using 4 textboxes, the problem is when I perform the multiplication operation on my function the output only shows up when I completed inputting values for the four textboxes, how can I make it so that the values would update just like in an addition operation?

Here's my code:

```
function ViewModel() {
var self =this;
self.firstNumber = ko.observable("");
self.secondNumber = ko.observable("");
self.thirdNumber = ko.observable("");
self.fourthNumber = ko.observable("");


self.Sum = ko.computed(function(){
return Number(self.firstNumber()) + Number(self.secondNumber()) + Number(self.thirdNumber()) +
Number(self.fourthNumber());
});

self.Product = ko.computed(function(){
 return Number(self.firstNumber()) * Number(self.secondNumber()) * Number(self.thirdNumber()) *
 Number(self.fourthNumber());
});
```

and here's my fiddle so far: http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/UvJAU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an empty string is treated by javascript as zero, when used as a number, so if any of your textboxes are blank, well, zero times anything is zero.

One way to handle this is to have it treat an empty string as '1', like so:

```
function defaultToOne(numString) {
    return numString === '' ? 1 : Number(numString);
}
```

Then your multiplication code can be:

```
self.Product = ko.computed(function(){
    return defaultToOne(self.firstNumber()) * defaultToOne(self.secondNumber()) * defaultToOne(self.thirdNumber()) * defaultToOne(self.fourthNumber());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nc9s/)

EDIT: This will show "1" as the product by default, if all of the text boxes are empty.  This isn't terrible, to some degree it's arbitrary what the product of zero numbers is.  But if you want to give a different default value, you can do something like this as the first line of your product function.

```
if((self.firstNumber() + self.secondNumber() + 
   self.thirdNumber() + self.fourthNumber()) === '') {
        return '';   
    }
```

Note that this is doing string concatenation with the '+' sign, rather than mathematical addition; this is a short  way of checking if all four of those boxes are empty.

Comment: Thanks! Retsam this is what I've been looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Empty textboxes will mean empty strings will mean 0 (zero). For addition this won't be a problem. For multiplication this means the product will be zero no matter what.

Make sure you somehow treat empty textboxes differntly (e.g. interpret it as 1 or ignore it alltogether).

Here's a non-efficient, non-elegant, but very explanatory way of doing this:

```
self.Product = ko.computed(function(){
    var n1 = self.firstNumber();
    var n2 = self.secondNumber();
    var n3 = self.thirdNumber();
    var n4 = self.fourthNumber();

    if (n1 === "" && n2 === "" && n3 === "" && n4 === "") { return ""; }

    if (n1 === "") { n1 = 1; }
    if (n2 === "") { n2 = 1; }
    if (n3 === "") { n3 = 1; }
    if (n4 === "") { n4 = 1; }

    return n1 * n2 * n3 * n4;
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fr7N4/).

Again, the above is not recommended production code, merely meant to be very verbose about what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply how can I do that in knockout.js can you show me :)

Comment: @a_miguel6687 First define how should it work.  What is 2 times an empty box supposed to equal?